# Correct syntax for php array_filter?

Tags: php

Here is my code, throwing an error with `Warning: Missing argument 2 for {closure}() in the first line`

```
$all_together = array_filter($info,function($each_one,$extra){

    $op = $each_one["something"];

    if($op <= $extra) return $each_one["what_I_need"];

});
```

**I need to use the $extra argument, independent of the input array elements**.
What am I missing exactly? tyvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like missing `use` keyword. Try this:

```
$all_together = array_filter($info, function($each_one) use ($extra) {
    $op = $each_one["something"];
    if($op <= $extra) return $each_one["what_I_need"];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, array filter should be used like this:

```
<?php
function test_odd($var)
{
return($var & 1);
}

$a1=array("a","b",2,3,4);
print_r(array_filter($a1,"test_odd"));
?>
```

Now only each element of the specified array will be passed to the function, if you must pass another argument, supply a default value to that argument in your function definition.